# Error while using GCM with IOS in Xcode Beta 7.2 with swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use the Google GCM for sending push notifications with IOS , i have followed all instructions and added the Google-Service-Info.plist file to my targets but when I initialise the app is crashing because which shows optional unwraping error at

```
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
```

I have installed the library using PODS and have included bride header with value

```
#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
```

I was able to read Plist file using custom code which prints all the keys

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

Comment: Optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is `nil`. Forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is `nil`. Refer in this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html). It means your variable is set to `nil`, but your code is expecting it to not be `nil`.

Comment: I understand the optional chaining but my question is why it is nil not why optional wrapping is failing

Comment: Sorry you did not get the question I'm not setting any value it's the Google api which is failing which I don't have any control over

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the crash report.